# Setting up Airbrake with a Swift Project

Tags: ios, swift, installation, airbrake

I'm new to Airbrake and I'm probably just doing something silly, but I've followed the steps outlined here to setup Airbrake in a Swift project: https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-ios

Seems simple enough but I'm getting two errors I can't resolve:

1)

> Use of unresolved identifier 'ABNotifier'

2)

> Use of unresolved identifier 'ABNotifierAutomaticEngironment'

I removed all the files, frameworks and directories and tried again in case that was the issue but same errors occur. I'm guessing for some reason this `ABNotifier` class isn't being recognized/not in scope?

I'm wondering if others have had this problem and this is an easy fix. Below is my line throwing the error:

> let key = "123456789"
>
> ABNotifier.startNotifierWithAPIKey(key, environmentName: ABNotifierAutomaticEnvironment, useSSL: true, delegate: self)

Any ideas?

Comment: After submitting a support ticket to Airbrake they updated their README on github which helped a little: https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-ios#running-the-notifier-in-swift. Basically instructions on how to create a bridging file...

Thing is, now I'm getting the following error: "This project uses features only available in iOS 4.0 and later" in their file: GCAlertView.h. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this error you mentioned in the comment...

> error: "This project uses features only available in iOS 4.0 and
>   later" in their file: GCAlertView.h

I ended up removing this line of code in `GCAlertView.h` in Airbrake. And it compiles fine. There's already minimum iOS version specified in the app bundle that prevents app installation. So I'd say checking this is pointless anyway.

```
#import <TargetConditionals.h>
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
//#ifndef __IPHONE_4_0 // hlung: this is not working correctly, remove for now
//#error This project uses features only available in iOS 4.0 and later
//#endif
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```